# How can I run flask in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, flask, command-prompt

I want to run the following code (which is executable in Ubuntu) or its equivalent in Windows:

```
python3 -m flask run
```

How can I run the above code in Windows? When I write it in the command prompt, the following appears:

`Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases`.

Comment: Did you install Python?

Comment: Yes, I have done so.

Comment: How did you do that? Does is run on its own?

Comment: I run Python codes in Pycharm.

Comment: add python to you path variables if you have installed python by going to environment variables or repair python and check the button `add to path` when repairing.

Comment: I have already done that.

Comment: **1.** Reboot & try again. The good old *have you tried turning it off and on again?* fixes more things than the length of π. **2.** Double check the path environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

Answer to the question:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/_/downloads/en/1.1.x/pdf/

Run the app:

```
set FLASK_APP=newproj
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Firstly you should create virtualenvironment for your flask project in yor desktop.

- install virtualenvironment : install virtualenvironment at your terminal or dos

  pip install virtualenv
- create a new folder for your project (i show you creating folder at terminal)

  mkdir newproj

  cd newproj

  virtualenv venv
- mkdir newproj : created new folder named "newproj"
- cd newproj : change directory to "newproj"
- virtualenv venv : created virtualenvironment named "venv"

and activate your venv.

```
C:\Users\name\abc> venv\Scripts\activate
```

Now, you can start install flask.

```
pip install Flask
```

If you use pycharm, open your folder in your editor. And create a new python file named hello.py (or another things). Write code below inside ypur python file.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World’

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Open pycharm editor and if venv is deactivate, activate venv. The above given Python script is executed from Python shell.

```
python hello.py
```

Debug Mode:

```
# app.run(debug = True)

app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8000,debug=True)
```

Summary :

```
$ export FLASK_APP=app.py # your python file name
$ set FLASK_APP = app.py
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ set FLASK_DEBUG = True
$ flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tricky part which I meet currently, for my situation I do download python too but cannot recognised via
`python --vesrion`

try with `py --version`, it work in my case and use py instead of python for other command too

Answer (score 0):

You can try with cmd in window 10 as below:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py # your python file name
```

```
set FLASK_APP = app.py
```

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

```
set FLASK_DEBUG = True
```

```
python -m flask run  # for window
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked and is straight to the point